# How to stop a nohup job that is using for loop in bash?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a nohup job that is running in background. It has a for loop that will repeat a task for 10 times. I have to use "kill " 10 times to stop it completely. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

what if you:

```
ps -ef|grep <script name>
```

get PID (second column)

then:

```
kill -9 <script PID>
```

Comment: At least try not to include the grep process into the list.

Comment: Thanks, looks like if a job is creating several PID, all of them needs to be stopped with the "kill -9" command. The "ps -ef|grep <script name>" comes in handy!

Comment: What if the script name happens to match other processes?  If you're editing the script, you may lose your editor.  This is messy.  Also, `kill -9` is only to be used as a last resort, as it removes the opportunity for a program to clean up after itself.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a mix of [pgrep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep) and [pkill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkill).

To find all your process matching your script this could be used:

```
pgrep -fl command
```

The `-f` will match against full argument list, and the `-l` stands from long output. To kill all the does process:

```
pkill -f command
```

To kill only the children process, once you find the parent PID you could try:

```
pkill -9 -P <parent pid>
```

This will send signal 9 `kill` to all processes with a parent process ID `-P <parent pid>`

To kill all the parent/child you could use:

```
kill -9 -PID
```

Notice the `-` on the PID, it means to send the signal to the PID and all its child processes.

Answer (score 0):

The `$!` variable stores the process number of the most recently backgrounded job.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do
  nohup sleep 300 &
  CMD_LIST="$CMD_LIST $!"
done
kill $CMD_LIST
```

This launches ten backgrounded commands that will each take five minutes (300 seconds). It stores their process IDs in `$CMD_LIST`.  After the loop, it kills them all.  Note the intentional lack of quotes in the `kill` command (each item in the list is a separate argument).